(Lattice Theory) Seeming disagreement between Distributive Lattice's Necessary-Sufficient condition and Necessary Condition

A lattice is distributive if and only if none of its sublattices is isomorphic to M3 or N5; a sublattice is a subset that is closed under the meet and join operations of the original lattice.

From Wikipedia

If a lattice is distributive then its every element has either 0 or 1 complement.

Say I find a lattice that doesn't contain a sublattice of M3 (Diamond Lattice) or N5 (Pentagon Lattice). Then we can say it is distributive by necessary-sufficient part. Now by necessary part, this lattice must have the property that every element must have at most one complement, right?
The Lattice in question
Now here's the issue. I'm sure there's nothing wrong with the theorems, but d has more than 1 complement, particularly I'd say, e, b, are both complements of d as the the join and meet of each of them with d is I and O respectively (seemingly). I can't find a way around this.
So it'd seem that the lattice isn't distributive, but then I can't find a sublattice in it that's isomorphic to M3 or N5 either (since that's necessary too). My current theory is it's there, and I just can't see it. Any ideas?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

$0, a, d, e, 1$ form a sublattice isomorphic to $N_5$.

Damn. I completely overlooked the relation by transitivity between 0 and e (due to o-b-e) forming the N5 sublattice (assume that's it right?). Thanks a lot!

@RuchirKadam That is right. $0, a, d, b, 1$ also form an $N_5$, as well as $0, a, b, e, 1$ and $0, d, b, e, 1$.

Completely right! And I'd even say 0, c, d, e, 1 form M3 (Though I assume the same isn't true for something like 0, a, b, c, 1 for having extra relations a-b, b-c not in M3 and same for 0, b, c, e, 1 ). Another interesting thing I found by applying this elsewhere is that it seems (looking at the wikipedia photo), the only difference between M3 and N5 is that N5 has an extra z-x relation. All the other relations are implicitly the same. Without that z-x, it'd be pretty much isomorphic to M3. Interesting.

@RuchirKadam Actually that's false. $0, c, d, e, 1$ is not a sublattice because sublattices are defined to be closed under the join and meet of the original lattice. In particular, say, the meet of $c$ and $d$ is $a$, which is not in $0, c, d, e, 1$.

@RuchirKadam Yeah, $M_3$ and $N_5$ are somewhat similar. In fact, if you look at it, they both model some sorts of having multiple complements: $y$ in both lattices has two complements. The difference is whether those complements are comparable, or are themselves complements to each other.
